# How do I get this JavaScript number guessing game to work without a "while" or "for" loop?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

**Here are the rules to the challenge:**

1. Generates and stores a secret, random number
2. Prompts the user for a number between 1 and 100
3. Responds to the user's number:

   - If higher, it says to pick lower
   - If lower, it says to pick higher
4. Repeats steps 2 and 3 until the user picks the correct number
5. Congratulates the user when they win!

**Do not use a 'while' or 'for' loop.** Use only functions.

I would normally use a loop to do this, but the rules state otherwise.  My code is below

```
var secretNumber = parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10) + 1;

var guessNumber = function(){

    var userNum = prompt("Pick a number between 1 & 100!");

    if(userNum > secretNumber){
       prompt("Pick Lower!");
    }
    else if(userNum < secretNumber){
       prompt("Pick Higher");
    }
    else{
       alert("Congratulations!!! You win!")
    }
};
```

Naturally my code stops after it runs through the "if else" statements.  How can I refactor this code to make the number guessing game work without loops?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Call the function again if the answer isn't correct.

Comment: Recursion! Call guessNumber() again inside the failing cases.

Comment: Make the function call itself at the end.

Comment: What kind of challenge is this?  Homework?

Comment: `parseInt` parses a string into an integer. Don't use it for numbers, because it will be unnecessarily slow. Use `Math.floor(num)` or `num|0` instead.

Comment: it's homework to brush up on JavaScript

Comment: @Oriol—the speed difference [*depends on the browser*](http://jsperf.com/parseint-vs-math-floor-2). The fastest way to floor a number across all browsers is the bit–wise OR operator: `|`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your function receive an argument, which you will use as the prompt message.

When the user fails, call your function again, but with another message. And voilà - Recursion :)

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer. Only problem is that if the user always reply with an invalid response, the stack grows forever. I know, that's the exercise... but just saying. 8-)

Comment: @AlexisWilke—unlikely. If the return isn't assigned and there's nothing further to execute, there's no need for the caller to hang around.